# Execution of program in C++ and OpenGL stops if mouse is not over

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl

I'm developing an application in C++ with a GUI in OpenGL. I have a  GUI with a background, some squared textures over the background and some text written next to the textures. When I run the program textures start to flash in blocks of n, and a string is printed on the gui in order to identify which block is flashing (I don't know how to better explain, is the P300Speller paradigm). I'm finding a problem due to flashes because the GUI doesn't update as long as I don't move mouse over the window! Can someone help me?

I'll try to post and explain some code. flashSquare is the function which makes textures flash. I use a boolean vector (showSquare) to indicate if the nth texture has to be normal or flashed (I load different textures) and a stack (flashHelperS) filled with integers which represent the stimulus sequence and the order of the flashing textures.

```
void flashSquare(int square){
if (firstTime){ // send stimulus command
    sendToServer(START_STIMULUS);
    fillStackS(); // Fill stack of stimuli
    firstTime = false;
    pausa = false;
}
if (pausa == false){
    cout << " Stack size : " << flashHelperS.size() << endl;
    if (!flashHelperS.empty()){ // If the stack is not empty
        int tmp = flashHelperS.top(); // select the next texture to flash
        flashHelperS.pop();   // and remove it from stack
        showSquare[tmp] = !showSquare[tmp]; // change bool of current                  
                                            // flashing texture
        cout << showSquare[tmp] << endl;

        if (showSquare[tmp]){
            counterSquares[tmp]++;
            sendToServer(tmp + 1);
        }

        square = tmp;
        glutPostRedisplay(); // Redisplay to show current texture flashed

        if (flashHelperS.size() >= 0) { //If the stack is not empty repeat                                              
            glutTimerFunc(interface->getFlashFrequency(), flashSquare, 0);
        }
    }
    else{ // If the stack is empty reset 
        initCounterSquare();
        sendToServer(END_STIMULUS);
        pausa = true;

        if (interface->getMaxSessions() == currentSession){
            sendToServer(END_CALIBRATION);
            drawOnScreen(); // Draw a string on the screen
            firstTime = true;
        }
        else currentSession++;
    }
  }
}
```

For example if stack has 8 items and maxSessions is 3, it means that glutTimerFunc calls flashSquare 8 times, making all the 8 texture flash, than I send to server END_STIMULUS code and repeat this operation other 2 times (because maxSessions is 3). When server receives END_STIMULUS and it is ready to receive more data it sends a code to my client, RESTART_S. When I receive RESTART_S (stack is empty and currentSession < 3) I call flashSquare again to start a new train of stimuli and flash.

```
if (idFromClient[0] == RESTART_S) {
    sendToServer(FLASH_S);
    firstTime = true;
    flashSquare(0);
}
```

When I call flashSquare manually the first time it works, but when I receive from server RESTART_S flashSquare is correctly called, indeed it sends to server START_STIMULS, firstTime = false, pausa = false, and it fills the stack. The execution of program goes on to the print of stack size and I can verify that all variables are correctly assigned (debugger shows that the function is called but it does nothing). The problem is that if I don't move mouse over the window with the textures, even if the window is focused, the execution doesn't go on.

Comment: Do you handle any mouse events for entering or leaving the window?  It's hard to help you if we don't have implementation details.

Comment: Show some code please. How is the rendering called? Which windowing system is used?

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I have no mouse handling in my program, so I don't understand why I have to move mouse! I posted some code with more comments! Can you give me any idea?

Comment: What is you "glutDisplayFunc" and do you expect it to be called each time you move the mouse? Also, do you use threading to do the networking? If so, you need to be careful, you should only call OpenGL functions in one thread or you need to switch the OpenGL context to the current thread each time you make calls to it.

Comment: I use all the OpenGL functions in the same thread. glutDisplayFunc has to be called automatically, i don't have a mouse handler, but it's really called only when i move mouse!